# PHP redis decr - decrease with 2 not with 1

Tags: php, redis

In PHP:

```
$redis->get("mykey") #Return 10;
$redis->decr("mykey"); #Return 9, but stored in Redis as "8".
```

Why is that happened? I'm using PHP7.2, PHP-redis 3.1.6-1

If I create key in the script and after that using decr, everything working properly, but if I just get it and decr, in redis is stored -2;

```
<?php
$this->memcache = new Redis();
$this->memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$this->memcache->get("mykey"); #Return 10;
$this->memcache->decr("mykey); #Return 9, but stored as 8;
?>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure you aren't decreasing twice? Can you post full code (including how you check the stored/return values?)

Comment: Even this return -2:

<?php
$memcache = new Redis();
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$memcache->decr('mykey');
?>